# Fleecing the Raffle

Tags: recreational-mathematics, lotteries

There is an [ICPC 2016 contest question](https://ncpc16.kattis.com/problems/raffle) about cheating in a raffle. It gives *n* names in the raffle box and *p* prizes, and you give back the optimal probability of winning a prize in the raffle by possibly cheating. The rules of cheating are that you lose your prize if your name comes up more than once.

But what if, instead, you are given *n* participants and *p* prizes, and you're not given how many cheat and by how much, but you're allowed to assume that everyone plays optimally. What is an approach to finding a solution to this problem?

*Edit:* As Saul points out, the probability is the same. So how many tickets do I (and everyone else) add?

*Edit:* As Saul also pointed out, the answer depends on whether lost prizes are redrawn or discarded. To be reasonable (not having stated this distinction first), an answer to either assumption is interesting.

*(This isn't a homework or a competition question.)*

Comment: If everyone plays optimally, everyone has an equal chance, so the probability that you win a prize doesn't change, does it?

Comment: OK, that's true. But how many tickets do I add? There seems to be something unstable about the answer, because if everyone added one, and you added one more (in some cases), that'd give you an edge, but then so would others.

Comment: If you only consider deterministic strategies (where you put in a set number, $k=k(n,p)$ slips), then everyone should also put in $k$ slips so the probability would be $k\times \binom {(n-1)k}{p-1} \big / \binom {nk}p$ which I believe is maximized at $k=1$ (but I have not checked that).  Maybe you can do better with probabilistic solutions...that's not clear to me.

Comment: @lulu Isn't it the same for every $k$?  If everyone does the same thing, everyone has the same chance of winning, and by linearity of expectation, that chance is $\frac{p}{n}.$  This is a really interesting question, but I can't seem to get a handle on it.

Comment: @lulu Actually, I don't think that $k\times \binom {(n-1)k}{p-1} \big / \binom {nk}p$ is correct, because it assumes that exactly $p$ tickets will be drawn.  But I have other chances to win.  Someone may be caught cheating, and then another ticket will have to be drawn.  I don't know how to express this combinatorially, but it explains how the probability can be constant.

Comment: @saulspatz   Yes....I guess I am assuming that exactly $p$ tickets are drawn and that, if a cheater is detected, that prize is simply not awarded.  It's certainly different if those cheating tickets are then redrawn.   The probabilistic idea I loosely tossed out might be relevant.  Maybe we all choose to put in $k$ tickets where $k$ is chosen from some distribution.  That preserves the possibility that I retain an edge over the competition.

Comment: If we assume that the prize isn't awarded when a cheater is caught, then the probability of winning is $(p-c)/n$ where $c$ is the expected number of cheaters caught, so it's best not to cheat, so that $c=0$.

Comment: Why would a prize be cancelled when a cheater is caught?  I know we're all just making things up (filling gaps in the original description), but that seems unfair!  :(  IMHO the most natural way to fill the gaps is this: keep drawing until (1) you have $p$ winners who are not caught cheating, or (2) you have $n-p$ people who are caught cheating, in which case you award the $p$ prizes to the others.  This way you always award $p$ prizes, the game remains zero-sum, and any symmetric strategy results in $p/n$ win prob for everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several partial solutions.

Assumption $1$: the OP question asks for an "optimal" strategy.  If you know your opponents' strategies before hand, then finding your optimal (assuming it exists) is a matter of tedious computation.  But if you must take into account your opponents being just as perfectly smart as you are, then the usual approach is to look at [Nash Equilibrium (N.E.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium), which is what I will do here.

Assumption $2$: the original specification is unclear on what to do after a cheat is found.  In this answer I assume an IMHO natural extension: the drawing continues until either (1) $p$ non-disqualified winners have been drawn, or (2) $n-p$ players have been disqualified in which case drawing stops and the prizes automatically go to the other players.  This way, $p$ prizes are always awarded, and the game remains zero-sum.

---

> Claim 1: For $n=2, p=1$, there is no optimal solution (fixed or probabilistic/mixed).

Proof: obvious, since more tickets is always better and there isn't a maximum integer.  Note that it is perfectly fine for a game not to have a N.E. due to the nature of the strategy set (here, pairs of integers).

---

For the rest, I only consider *fixed "all $k$" symmetric strategy set*, where each player puts in the same number of tickets, $k \ge 1$, and I ask whether it is a N.E.

When each player puts in $k$ tickets, by symmetry they have the same payoff.  Meanwhile by assumption $2, p$ prizes are always awarded, so the payoffs must sum to $p$, so each player's payoff (prob of winning) $= p/n$.

The definition of a N.E. is that, from player A's perspective, if every other player puts in $k$ tickets, then player A cannot do better by putting in a different number of tickets.

> Claim 2: For $n=3, p=2$, any fixed symmetric strategy set (i.e. any $k \ge 1$) is a N.E.

Proof: For $n=3, p=2$, two tickets drawn suffice to determine the winner - if they are different then those players are winners, whereas if they are the same then that player is disqualified and the others are the winners.  E.g. A wins if the two drawn tickets are: AB, BA, AC, CA, BB or CC; and A loses if the two drawn tickets are: AA, BC or CB.

The question therefore becomes, whether $\exists a \neq k$ s.t.

$$p_A := Prob(\text{A loses}) = {{a \choose 2} + k^2 \over {2k+a \choose 2}} < \frac13$$

If such an $a$ exists, then A can do better by putting in $a$ tickets instead of $k$ tickets, so the "all $k$" symmetric strategy set is not a N.E.

In the following, we rewrite $a = k+b$ for some integer $b$ (positive or negative):

$$
\begin{array}{}
p_A < \frac13 &\iff 3 (k^2 + {a (a-1) \over 2}) < {(2k+a) (2k+a-1) \over 2}\\
&\iff 6 k^2 + 3 (k+b)^2 - 3 (k+b) < (3k + b) ( 3k + b - 1)\\
&\iff 9 k^2 + (6b-3) k + 3 b(b-1) < 9 k^2 + 3 (2b -1) k + b(b-1)\\
&\iff 2 b(b-1) < 0
\end{array}
$$

But the last inequality is impossible for any integer $b$ (positive, zero or negative).  So, for any $k$, A cannot do better by putting in a different number of tickets, so the "all $k$" symmetry strategy set is a N.E. for any $k$. $\square$

Comments:

- Curiously, it turns out $b=1$, i.e. $a=k+1$, also yields $p_A = \frac13$.  However since this is not $< \frac13$, this does not affect the N.E. status.
- It is a surprise to me that "all $k$" is a N.E. for any value of $k$.  In the context of the OP's question, IMHO this means there is no "optimal".  E.g. when both opps are playing $k=17$, your optimal is $a=17$ or $18$, but when they are both playing $k=293$, your optimal is $a = 293$ or $294$, etc.  Anyway, this surprising result is probably just a quirk of $n=3, p=2$, because it is no longer true when...

> Conjecture 3: For $n=4, p=3$, a fixed symmetric strategy set is a N.E iff $k= 1$.

I have a partial proof plus some strong numerical evidence.

Again, three tickets drawn suffice to determine the three winners.  A loses if the tickets are: BCD (in any order), A+A+(not A) (in any order), or AAA.  So again the question become whether $\exists a \neq k$ s.t.

$$p_A = Prob(\text{A loses}) = {k^3 + 3k{a \choose 2} + {a \choose 3} \over {3k+a \choose 3}} < \frac14$$

Here are the numerical values of $p_A$ for $k \in \{1, 2, \dots, 10\}, a \in \{0, 1, 2, \dots, 15\}$

```
       a= 0   a= 1   a= 2   a= 3   a= 4   a= 5   a= 6   a= 7   a= 8   a= 9   a=10   a=11   a=12   a=13   a=14   a=15
       ----   ----   ----   ----   ----   ----   ----   ----   ----   ----   ----   ----   ----   ----   ----   ----
k= 1: 1.0000 0.2500 0.4000 0.5500 0.6571 0.7321 0.7857 0.8250 0.8545 0.8773 0.8951 0.9093 0.9209 0.9304 0.9382 0.9449
k= 2: 0.4000 0.2286 0.2500 0.3214 0.4000 0.4727 0.5364 0.5909 0.6374 0.6769 0.7107 0.7397 0.7647 0.7864 0.8053 0.8218
k= 3: 0.3214 0.2250 0.2182 0.2500 0.2972 0.3489 0.4000 0.4482 0.4926 0.5331 0.5697 0.6026 0.6323 0.6591 0.6832 0.7050
k= 4: 0.2909 0.2238 0.2088 0.2220 0.2500 0.2853 0.3235 0.3622 0.4000 0.4361 0.4701 0.5020 0.5316 0.5591 0.5846 0.6082
k= 5: 0.2747 0.2232 0.2059 0.2096 0.2260 0.2500 0.2782 0.3084 0.3394 0.3701 0.4000 0.4288 0.4564 0.4826 0.5074 0.5308
k= 6: 0.2647 0.2229 0.2053 0.2038 0.2130 0.2292 0.2500 0.2735 0.2985 0.3241 0.3498 0.3752 0.4000 0.4240 0.4472 0.4694
k= 7: 0.2579 0.2227 0.2055 0.2011 0.2057 0.2165 0.2318 0.2500 0.2701 0.2914 0.3132 0.3353 0.3572 0.3788 0.4000 0.4206
k= 8: 0.2530 0.2226 0.2062 0.2000 0.2015 0.2085 0.2197 0.2338 0.2500 0.2676 0.2861 0.3051 0.3244 0.3436 0.3627 0.3816
k= 9: 0.2492 0.2225 0.2069 0.1998 0.1991 0.2034 0.2115 0.2224 0.2354 0.2500 0.2656 0.2820 0.2988 0.3159 0.3330 0.3501
k=10: 0.2463 0.2225 0.2077 0.2000 0.1979 0.2002 0.2059 0.2143 0.2248 0.2368 0.2500 0.2641 0.2787 0.2938 0.3091 0.3245
```

Note that:

- In all cases $k=a \implies p_A = \frac14$ as expected.
- For $k=1$ there does not seem to be any $a$ s.t. $p_A < \frac14$.  This is strong evidence that "all $k=1$" is a N.E. (This case must be easy to prove, but I didn't bother.)
- For $k \in \{2, 3, \dots, 10\}$, there exists $a (< k)$ s.t. $p_A < \frac14$.  This proves "all $k$" is not a N.E. for these $k$.

  - The fact $a<k$ is (often) better for A means A is winning by virtue of others being caught cheating.
  - The best $a$ seems to be $\approx k/2$ or slightly less.
  - When $k=9$ or $10$, even $a=0$ (no tickets for A!) beats $\frac14$.
- I did not try $k > 10$, but again IMHO the numerical evidence is very strong that none of these "all $k$" would be a N.E.  E.g. it might be possible to prove that $a=1$ (e.g.) beats $\frac14$ whenever $k> 10$.